# Generate asynchronous interface for service side?

Tags: cxf

Does anyone know if cxf can generate something like this...

```
public void getEnrollment(EnrollRequest req, EnrollCallback cb);
```

where EnrollCallback has the method

```
EnrollCallback.enrollResponse(EnrollResponse resp);
```

so that it would be using nio under the covers and be completely asynchronous?

This would be instead of the usual methods it generates with `public EnrollResponse getEnrollment(EnrollRequest req);`

Is there a way to similarly do REST asynchronous interfaces?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hmmm, I only see how to do this for WSDLs not for plain REST/xml or REST/json POST and GETs :(

https://cwiki.apache.org/CXF20DOC/developing-a-consumer.html